# If/Then Conditional statement with Time Data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am running into and issue where I cannot compare date values between two data frames using Pandas.

I have two data frames loan_data & fiscal_periods.  Both contain start and stop dates.  I need to calculate the start & stop dates for the time the loan was in the period so that I can calculate the days the loan was in the period.  Example:

#### This Program Calculates the In-Period Loans and In-Period Loan days

#### Import Modules

````
import numpy as np

### Read in excel files ###
fiscal_periods = pd.read_excel('fiscal_periods.xlsx')
loan_data = pd.read_excel('TMPro Loan Program.xlsx')

#fiscal_periods.index
#print(loan_data)


### Calculate Loan Days by Loans ###
```import datetime```

```loan_data['Total Loan Days'] = (loan_data['End Date'] - loan_data['Start Date']) / pd.Timedelta("1 Days")```

### Determine Start Day for Loan Period Days Calc ###
np.logical_and

### Determine Loan in Period(s) ###

loan_data['FY22_P1'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P2'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[1,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[1,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P3'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[2,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[2,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P4'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[3,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[3,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P5'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[4,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[4,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P6'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[5,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[5,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P7'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[6,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[6,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P8'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[7,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[7,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P9'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[8,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[8,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P10'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[9,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[9,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P11'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[10,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[10,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY22_P12'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[11,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[11,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY23_P1'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[12,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[12,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY23_P2'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[13,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[13,'FP Start'])
loan_data['FY23_P3'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[14,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[14,'FP Start'])


###loan_data.to_excel('Loan Data Updated.xlsx')

### Date Comparison Practice ###

if loan_data['Start Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP Start']:
    loan_data['P1 Start'] = loan_data['Start Date']
else:
    loan_data['P1 Start'] = fiscal_periods.loc[0, 'FP Start']

Here is the errors I am getting:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 46>()
     25 loan_data['FY22_P1'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP Start'])
     26 #loan_data['FY22_P2'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[1,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[1,'FP Start'])
     27 #loan_data['FY22_P3'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[2,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[2,'FP Start'])
     28 #loan_data['FY22_P4'] = (loan_data['Start Date'] < fiscal_periods.loc[3,'FP End']) & (loan_data['End Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[3,'FP Start'])
   (...)
     43 
     44 ### Date Comparison Practice ###
---> 46 if loan_data['Start Date'] > fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP Start']:
     47     loan_data['P1 Start'] = loan_data['Start Date']
     48 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )'''

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Riley

Thanks for your help.  Here are the results you requested:

fiscal_periods.head(5).to_dict()
{'Fiscal Period': {0: 'FY22P1',
  1: 'FY22P2',
  2: 'FY22P3',
  3: 'FY22P4',
  4: 'FY22P5'},
 'Start Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-09-26 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-11-28 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-12-26 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-01-30 00:00:00')},
 'End Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-10-30 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-11-27 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-12-25 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-01-29 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-02-26 00:00:00')}}

loan_data.head(5).to_dict()
{'Status': {0: 'APPROVED',
  1: 'APPROVED',
  2: 'APPROVED',
  3: 'APPROVED',
  4: 'APPROVED'},
 'Loan Start': {0: Timestamp('2022-01-17 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-03-21 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-05-09 00:00:00')},
 'Loan End': {0: Timestamp('2022-07-25 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-09-24 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-07-30 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-07-08 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-08-13 00:00:00')},
 'Total Loan Days': {0: 189.0, 1: 187.0, 2: 89.0, 3: 67.0, 4: 96.0},
 'P1': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P2': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P3': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P4': {0: True, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P5': {0: True, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P6': {0: True, 1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P7': {0: True, 1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P8': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True},
 'P9': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True},
 'P10': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True},
 'P11': {0: False, 1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True},
 'P12': {0: False, 1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P1 Start': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False},
 'P1 DS': {0: Timestamp('2022-01-17 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-03-21 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-05-09 00:00:00')}}

***********UPDATE:************

###This Program Calculates the In-Period Loans and In-Period Loan days###

### Import Modules ### 
```import pandas as pd```

### Read in excel files ### 
```fiscal_periods = pd.read_excel('FY22 Fiscal Periods.xlsx')``` ```tmp_loans = pd.read_excel('TMP Loans.xlsx')```

###Create Index and Intervals for Active Loan Day Calculation### ```fiscal_periods_interval = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(fiscal_periods['Fiscal Start'])```

```tmp_loans_series = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(tmp_loans['Start Date'], tmp_loans['End Date']).to_series()``` 

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 12>()
     10 ###Create Index and Intervals for Active Loan Day Calculation###
     11 fiscal_periods_interval = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(fiscal_periods['Fiscal Start'])
---> 12 tmp_loans_series = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(tmp_loans['Start Date'], tmp_loans['End Date']).to_series()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/interval.py:286, in IntervalIndex.from_arrays(cls, left, right, closed, name, copy, dtype)
    260 @classmethod
    261 @Appender(
    262     _interval_shared_docs["from_arrays"]
   (...)
    283     dtype: Dtype | None = None,
    284 ) -> IntervalIndex:
    285     with rewrite_exception("IntervalArray", cls.__name__):
--> 286         array = IntervalArray.from_arrays(
    287             left, right, closed, copy=copy, dtype=dtype
    288         )
    289     return cls._simple_new(array, name=name)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py:492, in IntervalArray.from_arrays(cls, left, right, closed, copy, dtype)
    489 left = _maybe_convert_platform_interval(left)
    490 right = _maybe_convert_platform_interval(right)
--> 492 return cls._simple_new(
    493     left, right, closed, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, verify_integrity=True
    494 )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py:335, in IntervalArray._simple_new(cls, left, right, closed, copy, dtype, verify_integrity)
    333 result._right = right
    334 if verify_integrity:
--> 335     result._validate()
    336 return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py:604, in IntervalArray._validate(self)
    602 if not (self._left[left_mask] <= self._right[left_mask]).all():
    603     msg = "left side of interval must be <= right side"
--> 604     raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: left side of interval must be <= right side

fiscal_periods.dtypes

Fiscal Name             object
Fiscal Start    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

tmp_loans.dtypes

Status                           object
Start Date               datetime64[ns]
End Date                 datetime64[ns]
Length (Days)                     int64
Name                             object
Email                            object
Reason                           object
Site                             object
LOB                              object
Schedule                         object
AM Name                          object
AM Email                         object
Requester Notes                  object
Merlin Name                      object
Merlin Email                     object
Notes                            object
Assigned TMP                     object
Assigned TMP Email               object
Level                            object
GPS                               int64
Merlin                            int64
TC                                int64
Assigned TMPro DSID             float64
Assigned TMPro Name              object
Assigned TMPro Email             object
Assigned TTMPro DSID            float64
Assigned TTMPro Name            float64
Assigned TTMPro Email           float64
Assigned LAA DSID               float64
Assigned LAA Name                object
Assigned LAA Email               object
Loan ID                          object
Extension                        object
Loan Type                        object
Team Type                        object
Pilot Name                       object
TM DSID                         float64
Business Manager                float64
dtype: object
````

Comment: If you add some example data I'll give you a hand

Comment: use `fiscal_periods.head(5).to_dict()` and dump the results in your question so we can reproduce your data.  Do the same for `loan_data`.  Drop a comment once it's done.

Comment: What do you expect that to do?  `loan_data['Start_Date']` is a whole column.  It isn't meaningful to say `if column > column:`, because some can be True and some can be False.  Did you intend to do that row-by-row?

Comment: The intention is to take each row in the loan_data['Start Date'] column, compare it to the specific element in the fiscal_periods.loc[0,'FP Start'] and the greater of the values and populate a new column in loan_data called ['P1 Start'].  The issue is my brain is thinking in terms of excel where the formula works and converting it to python code and not fully understanding how to make this conversion work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining start and end points for the fiscal periods, how about we just define the break points that separate one fiscal period from the next.

This is probably just `fiscal_periods["Start Date"]` with the addition of an extra point for the last fiscal period, but let's just say for easiness that only the points in `fiscal_periods["Start Date"]`.

Create a pandas interval index using these break points.

```
import pandas as pd

fiscal_periods_ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(fiscal_periods["Start Date"])
```

Likewise, we'll create an interval index for the loan data, but use both the start and end dates.  Here you need to be careful with the dates.  If the last day of the loan is 2022-07-25, then the end timestamp needs to be 2022-07-26 because this will be the point (midnight) at which the day ends.  So you may need to adjust your "End Date" values.

Let's assume the "End Date" data is fine though, and create the interval index and convert it to a `pandas.Series`.

```
loan_interval_series = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(loan_data["Loan Start"], loan_data["Loan End"]).to_series()
```

This series will have the same index and values - which will be a `pandas.Interval` for each loan.

Next we'll use a function from a library called [`piso`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (pandas interval set operations).

The function [`piso.coverage`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.coverage.html) takes an interval, or interval index, and compares it's intersection to second interval index.  The second interval index can be treated as bins, which is what we'll do.

We'll apply this function to each interval in `loan_interval_series`.

```
import piso

loan_interval_series.apply(piso.coverage, domain=fiscal_periods_ii, bins=True, how="sum")
```

You'll get a `pandas.DataFrame` indexed by the loan intervals, whose columns are fiscal period intervals,and whose values are `pd.Timedelta` which is the length of overlap:

```
                         (2021-09-26, 2021-10-31] (2021-10-31, 2021-11-28] (2021-11-28, 2021-12-26] (2021-12-26, 2022-01-30]  
(2022-01-17, 2022-07-25]                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days                  13 days  
(2022-03-21, 2022-09-24]                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days 
(2022-05-02, 2022-07-30]                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days 
(2022-05-02, 2022-07-08]                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days 
(2022-05-09, 2022-08-13]                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days                   0 days
```

If you wanted True/False values instead then you could do this (assume the dataframe is called `df`)

```
df > pd.Timedelta(0)
```

or

```
df.astype(bool)
```

From here, you can replace your columns with Fiscal period names, reset your
index, basically whatever data manipulation you want - the hard stuff is done.

Disclaimer: I am the author of `piso`

Comment: Riley, I am traveling this week but will work on this as soon as I can.  From what you show, this looks like exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you very much, I will report out my results soon.

Comment: Riley, Wanted to report back in and let you know that it worked!  I am going to try it on a lager data set this week.  Thank you so much, this makes everything very simple.

Comment: when I try this on a larger data set I am running into an error:ValueError:                    left side of interval must be <= right side. any thoughts

Comment: Looks like you have an interval in the loan data where the start is after the end.  Run `loan_data[loan_data["Loan Start"] > loan_data["Loan End"]]` to confirm?

Comment: Riley, thanks I think I found a row of data where the Start Date was greater than the end date.  Let me fix.  Thanks for the heads up on this

Comment: Riley that worked. Thank you so much.  Final question.... Is there a way to append the output to my existing Loan Data worksheet, instead of creating the new Data Frame that it is creating?

Comment: You might be able to get away with `pd.concat` (axis=1).  This page will probably make it clear what you need https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: There is something to be said for [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) though.  In that case you would have a 1 column for fiscal periods (containing values like 'FY22_P1', 'FY22_P2') and then a column for the value.  You can get it in tidy data format through `pd.melt`.  Food for thought...

Comment: Riley, I was able to use pd.concat.  It's a bit sloppy but it works.  Again, I really appreciate the great assistance on this.  I think I have what I need.